# How to Migrate InfoPath XML form library to PowerApps

Tags: infopath, powerapp, xml, powerapps-canvas

I have started working on the migration project, which requires me to convert the SharePoint XML form library to PowerApps.

I have discovered that there is no simple solution to this problem and found the following approach, but I'd like to know if there is a better one.

1. Create a PowerShell script to export SharePoint XML form library data to csv/excel.
2. Make a new list and import the data into it.
3. Use the list as a data source in PowerApps.

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching the moment Power Apps was still a baby. Simply there's no direct solution for that, or precisely there's no one (yet) to build a tool to do this thing although it's technically possible.

Steps what you've described is the best approach so far and organizations been doing that too.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/transform-infopath

Comment: Disclaimer: Kudzu CEO.  We’ve built a platform that can do this and more: https://kudzusoftware.com/solution/infopath-replacement/

Answer (score 0):

Kudzu has a platform that can convert InfoPath form templates to Power Apps along with transforming the data from Form Libraries to SharePoint Lists or Dataverse Tables.

You can learn more here:

https://kudzusoftware.com/solution/infopath-replacement/

Disclaimer:  I am the CEO at Kudzu.